# Resuming loop after Run time Error 13 - Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

Hoping this is an easy one to resolve.  My code works as intended up until the Month(Range("K" & i)) does not contain a value in which case I get a Run time Error 13 - Type Mismatch.  When this occurs I would like the loop to continue running for the next i value.  I tried using On Error Resume, but it is resuming the next k value instead of i causing bad data.  Any help here is appreciated.

```
For i = 3 To 6

    For k = 16 To 36


        If Month(Range("K" & i)) = Month(Cells(2, k)) And Year(Range("K" & i)) = Year(Cells(2, k)) And Range("J" & i).Value > "0" Then

           Range("J" & i).Copy
           Cells(i, k).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        End If
    Next k

Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

Add another If to test whether it is a date or not first.

A couple more notes:

Get in the habit of specifying all parents to Range Objects, even if on the active sheet.  It will help in the future with more complicated code.

When only wanting values it is quicker to avoid the clipboard and assign the values directly.

```
For i = 3 To 6

    For k = 16 To 36
        With ActiveSheet
            If IsDate(.Range("K" & i)) Then
                If Month(.Range("K" & i)) = Month(.Cells(2, k)) And Year(.Range("K" & i)) = Year(.Cells(2, k)) And .Range("J" & i).Value > "0" Then

                   .Range("J" & i).Value = .Cells(i, k).Value

                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next k

Next i
```

Comment: When I try adding the extra IF as you show, It is giving me a Compile error:  Next without For and is highlighting the "Next" located before the k?

Comment: @MattR Try again now - Scott had left out the `End With`